# regex for letters or numbers in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java to process text using regular expressions. I am using the following regular expression

`^[\([0-9a-zA-Z]+\)\s]+`

to match one or more letters or numbers in parentheses one or more times. For instance, I like to match 
(aaa) (bb) (11) (AA) (iv)
or
(111) (aaaa) (i) (V)

I tested this regular expression on http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ and it is working. But when I use it in my code, the code does not compile. Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public class Tester {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\([0-9a-zA-Z]+\)\s]+");

            String[] words = pattern.split("(a) (1) (c) (xii) (A) (12) (ii)");

            String w = pattern.

            for(String s:words){

                System.out.println(s);

            }
    }
}
```

I tried to use \ instead of \ but the regex gave different results than what I expected (it matches only one group like (aaa) not multiple groups like (aaa) (111) (ii).

Two questions:

1. How can I fix this regex and be able to match multiple groups?
2. How can I get the individual matches separately (like (aaa) alone and then (111) and so on). I tried pattern.split but did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my final solution to match the individual groups of letters/numbers in brackets that appear at the beginning of a line and ignore the rest

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Tester {
    static ArrayList<String> listOfEnums;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        listOfEnums = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\([0-9a-zA-Z^]+\\)");
        String p = "(a) (1) (c) (xii) (A) (12) (ii) and the good news (1)";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(p);
        boolean isMatch = matcher.find();
        int index = 0;
        //once you find a match, remove it and store it in the arrayList. 
        while (isMatch) {
          String s = matcher.group();
          System.out.println(s);
          //Store it in an array
          listOfEnums.add(s);
          //Remove it from the beginning of the string.
          p = p.substring(listOfEnums.get(index).length(), p.length()).trim();
          matcher = pattern.matcher(p);
          isMatch = matcher.find();
          index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you want to escape any backslashes in the quotation marks with another backslash.  The Regex will treat it as a single backslash.  (E.g. call a word character \w in quotation marks, etc.)

Secondly, you got to finish the line that reads:

```
String w = pattern.
```

That line explains why it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your regex is incorrect. You want to match individual groups of letters / numbers in brackets, and the current regex will match only a single string of one or more such groups. I.e. it will match

```
(abc) (def) (123)
```

as a single group rather than  three separate groups.

A better regex that would match only up to the closing bracket would be

```
\([0-9a-zA-Z^\)]+\)
```

2) Java requires you to escape all backslashes with another backslash

3) The `split()` method will not do what you want. It will find all matches in your string then throw them away and return an array of what is left over. You want to use `matcher()` instead

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([0-9a-zA-Z^\\)]+\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(a) (1) (c) (xii) (A) (12) (ii)");

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: This works great. But what if I only want to match the individual groups of letters/numbers in brackets that appear at the beginning of a line and ignore the rest? For instace, if I have the following input "(a) (bb) (1) (iii) this is great news (22) (aa)" I want to match (a) (bb) (1) (iii) and ignore (22) (aa). Thank you Sam!

Comment: You can add `^` to the very beginning of the regex. But this will not work if your string is multiple lines long. You'd need to split it into multiple strings each one line long.